# Error: Got unexpected extra argument (app.py)

Tags: authentication, flask, python-venv

I am trying to build a login page using Flask and I can't seem to get the terminal to run the .py file and display the localhost page. Keep in mind that I am in the beginning stages of the login page so bare with me as far as the limited code available. Also other answers on SO didn't help.

This is the code I used in VSCode:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello from Flask!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I also created a venv within this application as well. I don't know if that caused the problem or not.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), to specify where your application is, use the parameter `--app` followed by the name of the relevant file.
To start in debug mode add the additional parameter `--debug`.
So the full command to start the application should be as follows.

```bash
flask --app app --debug run
```